# can .net WebBrowser control avoid popup SaveFileDialog instead of saving this file silently?

Tags: c#, .net, browser

lately I got a problem on using .net WebBrowser control. when redirect to a file downloading, the WebBrowser control popup the SaveFileDialog, I don't know if there is a way avoid this to let me choose a filename and save it to some location.

Thanks for any helps.

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? Did you figure out a way to do it? If so, which method did you use? I might be able to help since i'm looking into doing the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

You could handle the [`Navigating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx) event, detect that it's a file download, make the request yourself with `HttpWebRequest` or `WebClient`, and [cancel the navigating event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx) within the handler.

Comment: but I have another issue is that I see a cookie is write in domain .xxx.yy, but, I can't get this cookie by WebBrowser1.Document.Cookie.

Comment: @Weixiao: I'm afraid I can't help you on that front.

Answer (score 1):

You can [install your own custom download manager](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/03f65bb4-7e32-4238-a4f1-297e4ea8ccd2) by adding IServiceProvider to your WebBrowserSiteBase-derived class, which needs to be constructed in your webbrowser-derived class as the return value of the WebBrowser.CreateWebBrowserSiteBase virtual function.

In your download manager implementation you can write the file saving code. See https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSIEDownloadManager-8ab5d910 for an example to grab the download url. If the download url requires login, you need to grab session cookies. Check http://vbmhwb.sourceforge.net/ for an example.

Comment: Could you please give some specific example codes? Although this method seems to be the right way, it seems hard for newbies who only knows C# like me to understand